# Selenium "sendkeys" for upload file is not working under chrome but working under firefox

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I have no idea why the the same method is not working under chrome:

```
profileFilePath1 = "C:\\test\\1.zip";

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='upload']")).sendKeys(profileFilePath1);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Upload']")).submit();
```

No error in the console. It is told that the file is invalid, this is checkup by the browser.

But it is working perfect in firefox.

Comment: Is it entering the right file? Have you tried putting a pause in between the commands?

Comment: What error are you getting, exactly? Please provide a stacktrace.

Comment: Yes. I pause 1s pause. it should be the right file, because it is working under firefox

Comment: There is no error from the console.......

Comment: So what is the error you're getting then?

Comment: the loading zip file function should be done after sendKeys and submit. but It failed do the actual function.

Comment: I have created an issue since this is a very common problem across the board: <https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1309>